# Authenticate web app Using Saml 2.0 in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml, saml-2.0

I'm trying to Authenticate My  Web Application using "SAML" token , I understand All the theory part but cant find any good resource for Asp.net "SAML" Example for asp.net c#.
how to setup IDP(identity provider)locally for testing ,how to bypass my Legacy win-form authentication to SAML Authentication.

I have tried:

1. Onelogin
2. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56640/Performing-a-SAML-Post-with-C
3. https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml

Answer (score 3):

You need a SAML stack on your client side - look [here](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

A popular package is [Kentor](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) and there are some examples there.

Also be aware that the approach differs slightly depending on which SAML IDP you want to authenticate against.